# Entity Framework foreign key default value

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, default-value

I have tables Users and Roles. 
In Users table I have default value for RoleId column.
But I don't how I can make it work in EF4, for example, if I set RoleId property as `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed`

```
    _repository.Save(new User()
    {
        Login = "asdasd",
        Name = "sadqwqwd",
        Password = "wqdwqd"
    });
```

new user will be insert with default value, but if I want set RoleId in code

```
    _repository.Save(new User()
    {
        Login = "qqasdasd",
        Name = "qqsadqwqwd",
        Password = "qqwqdwqd",
        RoleId = 2
    });
```

it will ignore my RoleId value and set again default value.
If I remove `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed` option I cant insert user object wihtout RoleId value.
How I can resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Properties with DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed option will be ignored by EF in insert/update operations and can be set on database side only.

Remove DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed option from RoleId property and set default value in the constructor of User class.

Comment: I'm not interested to set default value in model, because default value is query, and in code I will should get context / repository in class constructor to get this value